# "Please don't use this tag for X purpose" - how strict are we regarding this disclaimer?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

We have several tags which contain a disclaimer of the kind:

> Please don't use this tag for **X** purpose, instead use (other-tag).

I decided to do a search for such tags to see whether this is being followed strictly, and here is what I found:

- **0** questions tagged [(cover)+(artwork)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover+artwork)
- **0** questions tagged [(cd)+(identify-this-album)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cd+identify-this-album)
- **0** questions tagged [(sample)+(identify-this-sample)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample+identify-this-sample)
- <s>**0** questions tagged [(sampling)+(bitrate)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling+bitrate)</s>
- **0** questions tagged [(unknown-performer)+(identify-this-artist)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-performer+identify-this-artist)
- **0** questions tagged [(unknown-composer)+(identify-this-artist)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-composer+identify-this-artist)
- <s>1</s> **0** questions tagged [(album)+(identify-this-album)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/album+identify-this-album)
- <s>1</s> **0** questions tagged [(names)+(identify-this-song)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names+identify-this-song)
- <s>1</s> **0** questions tagged [(names)+(album-title)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names+album-title)
- <s>1</s> **0** questions tagged [(names)+(song-title)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names+song-title)
- <s>3</s> **0** questions tagged [(bands)+(similar-artists)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bands+similar-artists)
- <s>3</s> **0** questions tagged [(bands)+(identify-this-band)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bands+identify-this-band)
- <s>3</s> **1** question tagged [(instrumental)+(identify-this-instrument)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrumental+identify-this-instrument)
- <s>5</s> **1** question tagged [(identify-this-artist)+(identify-this-band)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-artist+identify-this-band)
- <s>13</s> **0** questions tagged [(genre)+(identify-this-genre)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre+identify-this-genre)
- <s>13</s> **0** questions tagged [(music-video)+(identify-this-video)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-video+identify-this-video)
- <s>20</s> **0** questions tagged [(song-title)+(identify-this-song)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-title+identify-this-song)

Hence, the number of questions with "conflicting" tagging is low enough (= 64) to presume that it is just a mistake and can be corrected by retagging.

Does this sound appropriate to the community members? I personally think the current tag descriptions are appropriate, so the above conflicts should be resolved by retagging. I suggest that we do this in small batches so as to not flood the Home page.

---

Similar questions were asked earlier about the usage of the [genre](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genre) tag and specific genre tags here:

- [Usage of the [genre] tag](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/174/3955)
- [How to use tags for specific genres (like [rock], [jazz] etc.)?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/3955)

Answer (score 3):

The long and short of it is that we wanted to keep things as tidy as possible, but this stack doesn't get nearly as many questions as we had hoped.  As such, we don't really adhere to the suggestions as strictly as we wanted to.  Re-tagging is fine, as long as the re-tags make sense and aren't "forced" re-tags.