# Do we really need the [song-title] tag when we have the [identify-this-song] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

It looks like the [unknown-title](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unknown-title) tag was burninated back in 2016 because it was too similar to [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song).

It sure looks like most questions tagged [song-title](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-title) are either "What is the title?" or "Why is this song called X", the latter of which can often be resolved by a quick Google search. Furthermore, there are currently 31 questions with this tag and 776 tagged [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song).

I suggest we merge it with [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song) but I don't think anything too important would be lost if we simply removed it.

Why do we need [song-title](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-title)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up! I'm surprised that this discussion hasn't already been had.

I'll start by noting that the situation today is far better than it was a year ago: nearly half of the questions tagged [song-title] were also tagged [identify-this-song] until the conflicted tagging was cleaned up; see my earlier Meta question:

- ["Please don't use this tag for X purpose" - how strict are we regarding this disclaimer?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/480/3955).

Today, that number is far less.

Now, I agree that the [song-title] tag needs some cleanup, but merging it with [identify-this-song] would be too drastic.

> It sure looks like most questions tagged [song-title](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-title) are either "What is the title?" or "Why is this song called X", the latter of which can often be resolved by a quick Google search.

Questions like the first kind are, in my opinion, song identification questions in disguise, so they should be retagged as [identify-this-song].

However, questions like the second kind are definitely on-topic for us. One purpose of the sites in the SE network is to become a repository of commonly asked questions within each site's scope, so being easily Google-able is not a problem if the questions are otherwise well-written and on-topic. Moreover, one should not judge the very old questions on this site by the same standards for research that we have today, five years down the line.

---

I describe below how the questions currently tagged [song-title] are distributed:

#### Improper usage:  <s>8/31</s> 1/24

<s>4</s> 0 questions are about identifying a song:

- <s>[Can anyone identify the title of this Korean song in English?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4953/3955)</s>
- <s>[Persian song: can you please tell me what this song is called?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6757/3955)</s>
- <s>[Does anyone know the title of this background song on a video on Twitter?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/10387/3955)</s>
- <s>[Is there such a piece like Sonata No 9 for piano by Chopin?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/9835/3955)</s>

<s>3</s> 1 question is completely mistagged:

- (Off topic) [How do you start listening to songs? [closed]](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3330/3955)
- <s>[release](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/release) [If a song was released in 2014 as a single, and released the following year (2015) on an album, what's the true release date of the song?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4290/3955)</s>
- <s>[identify-this-sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-sample) [New version or extended sampling of Grace - Not Over Yet?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/8528/3955)</s>

<s>1</s> 0 questions are about the meaning of the lyrics, not the song title:

- <s>[What is Mumford & Sons' song "Holland Road" about?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3523/3955)</s>

#### Proper usage: <s>23/31</s> 23/24

15 questions are about the meaning of, or the reason for choosing, specific song titles:

- [How did the song "Plush" by Stone Temple Pilots get its name?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/632/3955)
- [The meaning of "Uptown Funk"](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/688/3955)
- [What is the meaning of the song "9-29-045" by Green Carnation?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/2147/3955)
- [Why are pianists included in The Carnival of the Animals?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/2808/3955)
- [What is "Uma Thurman" in the Fall Out Boy song?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3162/3955)
- [Meaning of BRMC's song's title (0.0770833333333333)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3256/3955)
- [Fifty Shades Darker, 'Code Blue' song by The Dream](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4867/3955)
- [What does "High C's" by Two Steps From Hell have to do with the ocean?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5715/3955)
- [INDK - Livin with even LES; what does LES stand for](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6019/3955)
- [What's the meaning of the title of the song "Echame la cupla"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6072/3955)
- [Why is Porcupine Tree's song '.3' named that way?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6387/3955)
- [What is the meaning of (Paean) in the title of Ed Sheeran's "How Would You Feel (Paean)"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6578/3955)
- [What does "Square-O" mean?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7297/3955)
- [Why is the title of this song "Bad"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/10443/3955)
- [Taylor Swift and Maroon 5 - same song titles?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/10546/3955)

5 questions are about the meaning behind generic phrases occurring in song titles:

- [Is there symbolism in the word "train" that is particular to rock music culture?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/920/3955)
- [What does "clean" mean at the end of the title of an instrumental jazz song on Amazon Music?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4595/3955)
- [Why are musicians so obsessed with rivers?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4669/3955)
- [Why does all the songs in Fucked Up's album "David Comes to Life" consist of three words?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4670/3955)
- [Rap songs not having featured artist in title](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6848/3955)

2 questions are about the "real" title of a song:

- [Sugarhill Gang - Apache (Jump on it) - real title?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7169/3955)
- [Knife Party - Destroy Them With.. Lasers or Lazers?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/7223/3955)

1 question is a list question about song titles:

- [Bands With Eponymous Album and Song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6221/3955)

---

Even with "only" 23 on-topic questions, this would still make [song-title] on of our more popular tags, sitting at the top of page 2 in the [tags list](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags)! Rather than merging [song-title] with [identify-this-song] or burninating [song-title], I suggest taking another look at the first 8 questions that I mentioned and seeing if retagging can/should be done (EDIT: this has been done).

It would also be a good idea to flesh out the proper usage of the [song-title] tag in its [tag info](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/song-title/info). Currently, it has an excerpt but no wiki.

---

<sup>Although it is not very relevant in this case, I'll add that some care needs to be taken before burninating a tag because a question can become [untagged] if the the only tag on that question is the burninated one. The list of questions solely tagged with [song-title] can be seen in [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/musicfans/query/701502/questions-with-one-tag).</sup>

Comment: I didn't want to make a separate post, but we also have [tag:identify-this-instrument] and [tag:instrument-identification]. Surely that's a better case for merging.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I took up the case for merging that pair of tags (among others) in this Meta question: [Can we merge our synonymised tags?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/662/3955)